# MySQL CURSOR loop adds ONE extra looping inside procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has 1 row but my procedure twice looping :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_Fetch_Returned_With_Serials;
    CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_Fetch_Returned_With_Serials`(OUT __Factor_Id bigint unsigned,OUT __Payment_Id bigint unsigned,IN __Payment_Amount decimal(16,3))
    BEGIN

        DECLARE Num BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE __Product_Id bigint UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE __Serials varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE _NEW_Factor_Id bigint UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;



        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT product_id, serials FROM tmp_table_returned_product_serial;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;


#         SET @Test = 0;
#         SELECT count(*) into @Test from tmp_table_returned_product_serial;
#         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
#             SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @Test;


        SET @Document_Id = 0;
        SET @Product_Id = 0;
        SET @Payment_Amount = 0;

        START TRANSACTION ;

        SET @Warehouse_Id = 0;
        SELECT id INTO @Warehouse_Id FROM Tb_Warehouses WHERE warehouse_branch_id = @Branch_Id LIMIT 1;

        SET @i = 0;

        OPEN cur;
        read_loop:
        LOOP

            IF done
            THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;

            FETCH cur INTO __Product_Id,__Serials;

            SET @i = @i + 1 ;

            CALL SP_Separate_Numeric_Values(`__Serials`);

            SET @Is_Returnable = 0;
            SET @Level_Id = 0;
            SET @Free_Day = 0;
            SET @Penalty_Percent = 0;
            SET @Factor_Type_Id = 0;
            SET @Currency_Id = 0;
            SET @Customer_Id = 0;
            SET @Factor_Id = 0;

            SET @Value = 0;
            SET @Real_Fee = 0;
            SET @Date_At = CURRENT_DATE();
            SET @Diff_Days = 0;
            SET @New_Factor_Id = 0;
            SET @New_Detail_Factor_Id = 0;
            SET @Receipt_Remit_Type_Id = 0;
            SET @Return_Penalty_Percent = 0;
            SET @Return_Penalty_Price = 0;
            SET @Document_Number = 0;


            SELECT id INTO @Factor_Type_Id FROM Tb_Factor_Types WHERE name = 'back_sale_factor';

            SELECT COUNT(NV.Number) INTO @Value FROM Numeric_Values NV;

            SELECT TP.is_returnable,
                   TU.level_id,
                   currency_id,
                   customer_id,
                   VF.id,
                   VF.product_id,
                   real_fee,
                   date_at
            INTO @Is_Returnable,@Level_Id,@Currency_Id,@Customer_Id,@Factor_Id,@Product_Id,@Real_Fee,@Date_At
            FROM Vw_Factor_Master_Details VF
                     INNER JOIN Tb_Factor_Detail_Serials TFDS ON TFDS.detail_id = VF.detail_id
                     INNER JOIN Tb_Products TP ON VF.product_id = TP.id
                     INNER JOIN Tb_Users TU ON TU.user_id = VF.customer_id
                     INNER JOIN Numeric_Values NV ON NV.Number = TFDS.serial_id
            LIMIT 1;

            IF (@Is_Returnable)
            THEN

                SET @Product_Title = '';
                SET @Error_Msg = '';

                SELECT IFNULL(TPT.title, TP.title_en) AS title
                INTO @Product_Title
                FROM Tb_Products TP
                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT title, product_id FROM Tb_Product_Translations WHERE locale = @Locale) TPT
                                   ON TP.id = TPT.product_id
                WHERE product_id = @Product_Id;
                SELECT message INTO @Error_Msg FROM Tb_Errors WHERE error_code = 1000028 AND locale = @Locale;

                SET @Error_Msg = REPLACE(@Error_Msg, ':product', @Product_Title);
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @Error_Msg;

            END IF;


            SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), @Date_At) INTO @Diff_Days;


            SELECT MAX(`number`) INTO Num FROM Tb_Factors WHERE year_id = @Fiscal_Year AND type = 'sale_factor';
            SET Num = ifnull(Num, 0) + 1;


            SELECT col
            INTO @Free_Day
            FROM (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(TS.value, CONCAT('$.', @Level_Id)), '$.free_day') AS col
                  FROM Tb_Settings TS
                  WHERE `key` = 'returned_product') TS
            WHERE col IS NOT NULL
            LIMIT 1;


            SELECT col
            INTO @Penalty_Percent
            FROM (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(TS.value, CONCAT('$.', @Level_Id)), '$.penalty_percent') AS col
                  FROM Tb_Settings TS
                  WHERE `key` = 'returned_product') TS
            WHERE col IS NOT NULL
            LIMIT 1;

            IF (@Diff_Days > @Free_Day)
            THEN
                SET @Payment_Amount = @Payment_Amount + ((@Real_Fee - (@Real_Fee * @Penalty_Percent / 100)) * @Value);
                SET @Return_Penalty_Percent = @Penalty_Percent;
                SET @Return_Penalty_Price = @Real_Fee * @Penalty_Percent / 100;

            ELSE
                SET @Payment_Amount = @Payment_Amount + @Real_Fee;
            END IF;

            IF (_NEW_Factor_Id = 0)
            THEN

                INSERT INTO Tb_Factors (type, sale_place, product_type, company_id, branch_id, cash_desk_id, type_id,
                                        year_id,
                                        currency_id, finaler_id, signature_id, customer_id, final_at, signature_at,
                                        reference_factor_id, creator_id, number)
                VALUES ('sale_factor', 'branch', 'product', @Company, @Branch_Id, NULL, @Factor_Type_Id,@Fiscal_Year,
                        @Currency_Id, @Auth_User, @Auth_User, @Customer_Id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                        @Factor_Id, @Auth_User, Num);

                SET _NEW_Factor_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();


            END IF;


            INSERT INTO Tb_Factor_Details (product_id, value, real_fee, fee, factor_id, creator_id, return_penalty_percent,
                                           return_penalty_price)
            VALUES (@Product_Id, @Value, @Real_Fee, @Real_Fee, _NEW_Factor_Id, @Auth_User, @Penalty_Percent,
                    @Return_Penalty_Price);

            SET @New_Detail_Factor_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();


            INSERT INTO Tb_Factor_Detail_Serials (serial_id, detail_id)
            SELECT NV.Number, @New_Detail_Factor_Id
            FROM Numeric_Values NV;


            SELECT id INTO @Receipt_Remit_Type_Id FROM Tb_Receipt_Remit_Types WHERE name = 'return_of_sales';



            IF (@Document_Id = 0)
            THEN
                SELECT document_number
                FROM Tb_Documents
                WHERE fiscal_year_id = @Fiscal_Year
                ORDER BY document_number DESC
                LIMIT 1
                INTO @Document_Number;
                SET @Document_Number = @Document_Number + 1;

                INSERT INTO Tb_Documents (type, factor_id, warehouse_id, receipt_remit_type_id, fiscal_year_id,
                                          document_number,
                                          creator_id, company_id)
                VALUES ('receipt', _NEW_Factor_Id, @Warehouse_Id, @Receipt_Remit_Type_Id, @Fiscal_Year, @Document_Number,
                        @Auth_User, @Company);

                SET @Document_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
            END IF;


            INSERT INTO Tb_Document_Details (product_id, value, confirmed_at, confirmed_by, creator_id, document_id)
            VALUES (@Product_Id, @Value, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), @Auth_User, @Auth_User, @Document_Id);

            SET @Document_Detail_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

            INSERT INTO Tb_Detail_Serial_Numbers (serial_number_id, detail_id, origin_cost_center_id, confirmed_at,
                                                  confirmed_by)
            SELECT NV.Number, @Document_Detail_Id, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), @Auth_User
            FROM Numeric_Values NV;

        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur;

        SET @Type_Id = 0;
        SELECT id INTO @Type_Id FROM Tb_Payment_Types WHERE name = 'cash' LIMIT 1;

        INSERT INTO Tb_Receive_Payment (model_type, model_id, factor_id, type_id, receive_amount, payment_amount, year_id,
                                        creator_id)
        VALUES ('cashdesk', NULL, _NEW_Factor_Id, @Type_Id, 0, @Payment_Amount, @Fiscal_Year, @Auth_User);

        SET @Payment_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        COMMIT ;

                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @i;

        SET __Factor_Id = _NEW_Factor_Id;
        SET __Payment_Id = @Payment_Id;
        SET __Payment_Amount = @Payment_Amount;




    END
```

Comment: Can you try this: set done = 0; (but right before the OPEN cur). And then test it like this:  IF done = 1 then ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move  FETCH cur INTO __Product_Id,__Serials; to before if done